# Linux kernel waking laptop due to custom M.2 E-key chip

Tags: kernel, shutdown, suspend, pci, wake-on-lan

I recently swapped my internal wifi card with a [Coral Edge Tpu](https://coral.ai/products/m2-accelerator-dual-edgetpu/)
Straight to the problems occurred:

- laptop doesn't stay in sleep state: it immediately wakes up, even with the lid closed
- laptop doesn't stay in shutdown state: it always reboots, even with halt / shutdown -h
  My system is a quad-boot system: Windows 10, Kubuntu 20.04, kali 20.04 and a linux-from-scratch system.

This problems occurr only with linux kernels: when booting Windows everything works fine.
Kernel versions tried so far: 4.19, 5.4.0, 5.2, 5.8.3, 5.9.0
It shouldn't be a driver problem: I only have them installed on the Kubuntu installation, and the problems remain regardless of the drivers.
Any idea about how to solve this behiavour? I thought about tuning some kernel parameters but I've no idea what to look for

inxi -Fxz:

```
    System:    Kernel: 5.9.0-050900-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5  
       Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)  
    Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook S15 X510UF v:  1.0 serial: <filter>  
       Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X510UF v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI:  American Megatrends v: X510UF.303  
       date: 04/17/2019  
    Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: N/A condition: N/A model: N/A status:  Unknown  
    CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8250U bits: 64 type:  MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A  
       L2 cache: 6144 KiB  
       flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx  bogomips: 28800  
       Speed: 2289 MHz min/max: 400/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1:  2077 2: 3400 3: 1354 4: 671 5: 2118 6: 2338  
       7: 3034 8: 1746  
    Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0  
       Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce MX130] vendor: ASUSTeK driver:  nvidia v: 455.38 bus ID: 01:00.0  
       Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa  
       resolution: 1366x768~60Hz  
       OpenGL: renderer: GeForce MX130/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA  455.38 direct render: Yes  
    Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel  
       bus ID: 00:1f.3  
       Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.9.0-050900-generic  
    Network:   Message: No Device data found.  
       Device-1: Realtek RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN  Adapter type: USB driver: rtl88XXau  
       bus ID: 1-1:5  
       IF: wlx00c0caac36b4 state: up mac: <filter>  
       IF-ID-1: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown  mac: <filter>  
       IF-ID-2: veth2f79591 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full  mac: <filter>  
    Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.36 TiB used: 201.11 GiB (14.4%)  
       ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51  GiB temp: 35 C  
       ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO M.2 500GB  size: 465.76 GiB  
    Partition: ID-1: / size: 69.00 GiB used: 45.15 GiB (65.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5  
       ID-2: /home size: 209.57 GiB used: 114.93 GiB (54.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6  
       ID-3: swap-1 size: 9.08 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda7  
    Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 49 C  
       Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 3100  
    Info:      Processes: 268 Uptime: 1h 17m Memory: 15.52 GiB used: 2.29 GiB (14.8%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5  
       Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```